# Omniauth not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, omniauth

So I've installed the Omniauth gem, and it's currently implemented with Devise.

Devise is functioning great however getting Omniauth setup has been a battle and it's something i'm still trying to get working. I am using Omniauth with Twitter authentication.

***The problem:*** When I click on the 'Login with twitter' icon, it re-directs me to twitter as it should, I then am prompted to enter my twitter credntials..all is well until it begins to redirect (callback).

When it attempts to re-direct to my app i get the following error:

#### NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

app/models/user.rb:14:in `apply_omniauth'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

***Registration controller:***

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  private

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

***Authentications controller:***

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

***User.rb (Users controller)***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
    authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])

  end

  def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
  end
end
```

## Please read update:

> I just ran into this following RailsCast.
>
> The tutorial says to run:
>
> rails g nifty:scaffold authentication user_id:integer \
>           provider:string uid:string index create destroy
>
> But not having the nifty scaffold stuff on my machine, I just ran
>
> rails g scaffold authentication user_id:integer \
>           provider:string uid:string index create destroy
>
> Which behaves differently. Instead of creating stub 'index', 'create',
>   and 'destroy' controller methods, it created fields in the database.
>
> ### How can i remove the fields?

Comment: which fields you wish to remove ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `User.rb` line #14

instead of `omniauth['user_info']['email']` it should be `omniauth['info']['email']`

For [nifty generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) you should have

`gem "nifty-generators", group: :development`

in you Gemfile

Try `rails g scaffold --help` to see the available options for scaffold generator

You may also have a look at this amazing rails-cast too [generators-in-rails-3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks @swap.nil, but now I am getting this error: " Can't mass-assign protected attributes: provider, uid " What should i do?

Comment: add `:provider` and `:uid` to your Authentication model white list attributes i.e. to `attr_accessible :provider, :uid`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

Comment: @TonyP try using http://api.rubyonrails.org/ more often it's an awesome place to learn `Rails` ;-)

Comment: great source, duly noted. i've added the attr_accessible :provider, :id to the authentications model but i'm getting: undefined method `attr_accessible' for AuthenticationsController:Class

Comment: @TonyP white list is only for `ActiveRecord::Base` and not for `ActionController::Base` not need to include `attr_accessible` in Controller

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you can clear this up for me a bit, i'm not sure what you mean when you say add attr_accessible :provider, :id to auth model. Where exactly am i adding it? feels out of place

Comment: well I guess you read it [here](http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/02/09/facebook-connect-with-rails-omniauth-devise/) I assume you have generated you Authentication model and the migrations are up. So in `Authentication` model `app/models/authentication.rb` in there add this line `attr_accessible :provider, :uid`

Answer (score 1):

Try Replacing

```
omniauth['user_info']['email']
```

by

```
omniauth['email']
```

you can use a wrapper method like this

Update: Wrapper for omniauth

```
def omni_conversion(omniauth)
    {
      # Required For Social Network Creation
      access_token: omniauth.credentials.token,
      link: omniauth.extra.raw_info.link,
      provider: omniauth.provider,
      providerid: omniauth.uid,

      # Required For User Creation
      birthday: omniauth.extra.raw_info.birthday,
      email: omniauth.info.email,
      first_name: omniauth.info.first_name,
      gender: omniauth.extra.raw_info.gender,
      last_name: omniauth.info.last_name,
      middle_name: omniauth.info.middle_name,
      picture: omniauth.info.image,
      timezone: omniauth.info.timezone,
      username: omniauth.extra.raw_info.username
     }
  end

omniauth = omni_conversion(omniauth)
```

The advantage is you get symbols to use directly. and you can pass them directly to models.

Comment: Thanks @Abibullah Rahamathulah but I am now getting this error: " Can't mass-assign protected attributes: provider, uid "

Comment: When U see this kind of error, You should follow the suggestion given by @swap.nil.